# What firmware works with a D-Link DIR-600?

Tags: openwrt, firmware, dd-wrt

I'm planning on getting a D-Link DIR-600 to be used as a WLAN access point, and for WEP/WPA certificate management.

I know it works with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), and [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/), but not [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). Now, I've been looking what firmware I can put on that device, prior to getting it. Tomato is my favorite option, but since it doesn't work with the router, I'm getting second thoughts about getting it at all.

If you happen to have a better suggestion for a router, please do so, but I'd like to stay in the same price range as the DIR-600 (around 25€).

Comment: vote to close, or migrate if you think this should be elsewhere.

Comment: @xeno (We don't have any migration paths, so we can't actually vote to migrate)

Comment: @michael wtf... when do we get these things? I thought we launched

Comment: @xeno They're added to sites that demonstrate a need for them, and we don't migrate very often, so probably a pretty long time

Comment: @michael well do with this what you want... I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DD-WRT and OpenWRT are your two best bets for the D-600. They can do most o fwhat Tomato can do, so unless you need something specific to Tomato, this router should be fine.